# Debian slow start after upgrade - Gnome/Wayland issue ? (Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid - Gnome 3.34.1)

Tags: boot, debian, gnome, wayland

After upgraded my Debian testing few weeks ago, I realise that my boot take **1 minute** more to show login screen. 1 minute is a timeout during boot. I did'nt notice that before because I always use suspend mode (it's still fast that way, even with this issue) and I'm not in front of screen during boot step.

I think it's a bug in Gnome 3.34 or Wayland, but I'm not sure... look at the timestamp pass from *11:14:01* to *11:15:02*. Thank you for any advices.

```
$ systemd-analyze

Startup finished in 3.416s (kernel) + 6.440s (userspace) = 9.856s 
graphical.target reached after 6.430s in userspace
```

---

### **Here's parts of boot log that hightlight the issue :**

```
$ journalctl -xb -p err

-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-10-29 11:13:30 CET, end at Tue 2019-10-29 11:47:38 CET. --

[...]

-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Started GNOME Session is not yet stable (running for <2 minutes).
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Reached target Session services which should run early before the graphical session is brought up.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Started Monitor Session leader for GNOME Session.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian gnome-session-c[725]: Error creating FIFO: Le fichier existe
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian agent-launch[724]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/117/openssh_agent
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian agent-launch[724]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=openssh
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Reached target Tasks to be run before GNOME Session starts.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Starting GNOME Session Manager (session: gnome-login)...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian agent-launch[724]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/117/openssh_agent; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian agent-launch[724]: echo Agent pid 724;
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Started GNOME Session Manager (session: gnome-login).
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Reached target GNOME Session Manager is ready.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Starting GNOME Shell on Wayland...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian gnome-shell[734]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': Failed to activate universal planes: Opération non permise
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian gnome-shell[734]: Failed to create backend: No GPUs found
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-shell-wayland.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Dependency failed for GNOME Shell on Wayland.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué, avec le résultat dependency.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Dependency failed for GNOME Wayland Session.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué, avec le résultat dependency.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Dependency failed for GNOME Wayland Session (session: gnome-login).
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a échoué, avec le résultat dependency.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-wayland@gnome-login.target: Job gnome-session-wayland@gnome-login.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-wayland.target: Job gnome-session-wayland.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-wayland.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-shell-wayland.target: Job gnome-shell-wayland.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-shell-wayland.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction for gnome-shell-disable-extensions.service/start is destructive (gnome-session-stable.timer has 'stop' job queued, but 'verify-active' is included in transaction).
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-shell-wayland.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job, ignoring: Transaction for gnome-shell-disable-extensions.service/start is destructive (gnome-session-stable.timer has 'stop' job queued, but 'verify-active' is included in transaction).
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-stable.timer: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Stopped GNOME Session is not yet stable (running for <2 minutes).
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Stopped target GNOME Session Manager is ready.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:13:32 debian systemd[700]: Stopping GNOME Session Manager (session: gnome-login)...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à s'arrêter
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 

[...]

oct. 29 11:13:41 debian systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 29 11:14:00 debian systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit systemd-fsckd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 29 11:14:01 debian dbus-daemon[558]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
oct. 29 11:14:01 debian pulseaudio[712]: E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
oct. 29 11:14:01 debian systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit systemd-hostnamed.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 29 11:14:01 debian systemd-timesyncd[505]: Synchronized to time server for the first time [2a00:1080:807:200::5:1]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
oct. 29 11:15:02 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
oct. 29 11:15:02 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: Killing process 729 (gnome-session-b) with signal SIGKILL.
oct. 29 11:15:02 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit UNIT has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 9.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Stopped GNOME Session Manager (session: gnome-login).
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Stopped target Tasks to be run before GNOME Session starts.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Stopping Monitor Session leader for GNOME Session...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à s'arrêter
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à s'arrêter.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Stopped target Session services which should run early before the graphical session is brought up.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Reached target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Starting Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a commencé à démarrer.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: gnome-session-monitor.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Stopped Monitor Session leader for GNOME Session.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son arrêt.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian gdm-launch-environment][694]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user Debian-gdm
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Started Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) UNIT a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 29 11:15:03 debian systemd[700]: Startup finished in 1min 30.496s.
-- Subject: Le démarrage du gestionnaire utilisateur est terminé
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 

[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups ... forgot this question!
The problem was solved by an update of Debian/Gnome last month.